# Why do addresses in array of char type pointers wsklan[0] and wsklan[0][0] differ?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

Might be a silly question for you, and I couldn't find a good question for that, but the thing is - I don't understand and I'm asking you to explain that concept to me so I can understand, I would be really grateful.

So, the thing is - I was wondering, first of all, why that line of code:

```
printf("address of wsklan[0] %p\n", &wsklan[0])
```

would print different address than:

```
printf("address of wsklan[0][0] %p\n", &wsklan[0][0]);
```

I'm guessing that's because in the first case, that is an address of a pointer, and in the second one - an address of a char variable. But why exactly the address is different? I thought that the address of wsklan[0] is the address of the first char.

How is the string stored in memory? Is the string one after  another in memory? So if I type 'onetwo' and second string 'threefour', it would be one after another?

And second question - why can't I use the puts function like this?:

```
puts(wsklan+1)
```

but I can use it like this?

```
puts(wsklan[1])
```

Full code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read(char *z, int amount);

int main(void){
    
    char data[20][300];
    char * wsklan[20];
    read(data[0], 300);
    read(data[1], 300);
    wsklan[0] = data[0];
    wsklan[1] = data[1];
    printf("addres wsklan[0][0] %p\n", &wsklan[0][0]);
    printf("addres wsklan[1][0] %p\n", &wsklan[1][0]);
    puts(wsklan[0]);
    puts(wsklan[1]);
    putchar(*wsklan[1]);

    return 0;
}

char *read(char *z, int amount){
    char * res;

    int i = 0;

    res = fgets(z, amount, stdin);

    if(res){
        while(z[i] != '\n' && z[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        if(z[i] != '\n')
            z[i] = '\0';
        else
            while(getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
    }

    return res;

}
```

Thank you for your understanding and helping me in understanding the concept in general. That code snippet is from Stephen Prata's C book, I modified it slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the declaration is `char * wsklan[20];`.

In the expression `&wsklan[0]`, `[]` takes precedence over `&`, so we get pointer number 0. Then `&` gives the address of that pointer. Since it's the first item in the array, you can assume it's the same address as obtained by `&wsklan`.

In the expression `&wsklan[0][0]` we also get pointer number 0, then again `[]` takes precedence over `&` so we get character number `0` in the array that pointer number 0 points at. Then `&` gives the address of that single character. What address that is depends on where you set the pointer to point at. It makes perfect sense that it points at a different address than where the pointer itself is stored. (Since a pointer pointing at its own address would be quite useless.)

Second question: `wsklan[1]` is 100% equivalent to `*(wsklan + 1)`. So it has a different meaning than just `wsklan + 1`. Since the variable is of type "array of character pointers", it "decays" into a pointer to the first item when used in an expression. That would be a pointer to character pointer, `char**`. That's not what printf expects - you'll have to de-reference it into a plain `char*` first.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I had a problem with dereferencing the variables first in my head. So you're right, &wsklan[0] is exactly the address of the first pointer in the array. Now I see, because to see the address that the first element in the array of pointers points, I have to do *(&wsklan[0]), not &wsklan[0]. So the second question was pretty similar, it all came down to understand what exactly am I dereferencing. Thank you very much @Lundin.

Comment: @dippie `*(&wsklan[0])` does not need parentheses, again `operator*` has lower precedence, so this is equivalent to `*&wsklan[0]` which is equivalent to simply `wsklan[0]`.

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right, you're right. I was just editing the comment, but 5 minutes have passed. I've meant "I have to do &(*wsklan[0]), not &wsklan[0]." Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @dippie That's again the same as just `wsklan[0]`: Fetching the address of a value a pointer points to gives, guess, the value stored in the pointer...

Comment: @Aconcagua ohhh, now I see what you've meant. You're right, it prints out the same thing, no need to dereference it and then use the ampersand. Thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

For argument's sake, let us assume the following:

- `sizeof(char)` is 1 (by definition)
- `sizeof(char *)` is 4 (e.g. on a system with 32-bit pointers)
- `char data[20][300]` is stored at address 10000 (arbitrary)
- `char *wsklan[20]` is stored at address 20000 (arbitrary)

Then:

- `&wsklan[0]` is converted to `(char **)20000`
- `&wsklan[1]` is converted to `(char **)20004`
- `&wsklan[2]` is converted to `(char **)20008`

> Note: Unary `&` has lower precedence than `[` `]`, so `&wsklan[0]` means `&(wsklan[0])`.

and:

- `data[0]` and `&data[0][0]` are converted to `(char *)10000`
- `data[1]` and `&data[1][0]` are converted to `(char *)10300`
- `data[2]` and `&data[2][0]` are converted to `(char *)10600`

> Note: `&data[0][0]` means `&((data[0])[0])`.

After:

```
    wsklan[0] = data[0];
    wsklan[1] = data[1];
```

then:

- `wsklan[0]` and `&wsklan[0][0]` are converted to `(char *)10000` (same as `data[0]` and `&data[0][0]`)
- `wsklan[1]` and `&wsklan[1][0]` are converted to `(char *)10300` (same as `data[1]` and `&data[1][0]`)

Comparing `&wsklan[0]` and `&wsklan[0][0]` from above to summarize:

- `&wsklan[0]` is converted to `(char **)20000`
- `&wsklan[0][0]` is converted to `(char *)10000` (same as `&data[0][0]`)

Comment: I see and I understand. Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot too. Thanks for helping me to understand the concept.